# Facebook graph API 2.1 signed request values

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to use new Facebook graph API now.
I have a page tab application.
So in old API (1.0) i just Pars a signed_request parameter and took out of it page.liked parameter to determine if user liked my page or not.
In new API i get parsed signed_request like this:

{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","issued_at":1407738045,"page":{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx","admin":true},"user":{"country":"ru","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}}}

On Facebook documentation i find: "This field will no longer be included for any app created after the launch of v2.1 (August 7th, 2014), and will be permanently set to true for all other apps on November 5th, 2014"

So how i can know in new API if user liked page?

Comment: This will be simply not working anymore, and this is by design from Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its now against's Facebook's policy to gate access to an app or content within an app based on if the user has liked a page. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy

As part of this, they've removed the technical ability to determine if the user has liked the page when an app is rendered in a page tab.